# check if device already exists or not in a group

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to use list expression to check if device already exists or not in a group while posting? The user might post the same device in a same group. I have done the posting part but dont know the efficient way to check the existence of device in a group.

Here is my post function

```
def post(self, request, token=None, format=None):
    group_instance = Group.objects.get(token=token)
    for device_token in request.data['devices']:
        # device = Device.objects.get(token=device_token, owner=request.user)
        device = Device.objects.select_related('group').get(token=device_token, owner=request.user)
        # will not hit the db as value is already fetched in the previous query
        device.group = group_instance
        # check if device exist in a group or not
        print('device', device)
        device.save()
    return Response(device, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: You create some resource when you use POST. What do you create?

Comment: resource? I did not understand you. It is the complete view part. I have a simple serializer and nothing else

Comment: So you don't build a [REST](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html) API and your question is not related with DRF. Could you explain more what do you want to archive? Why you can't just do `if device.group != group_instance`?